# batchSize field name ignored in Field Projection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a user_batch collection. It contains following documents:

```
[{
  _id: ObjectId("594baf96256597ec035df23c"),
  name: "Batch 1",
  batchSize: 30,
  users:[]
 },
 {
  _id: ObjectId("594baf96256597ec035df234"),
  name: "Batch 2",
  batchSize: 50,
  users:[]
 }]
```

In find query I want to project only **name** and **batchSize**. But when I execute find query from nodejs, I'm getting entire document in query result. Query:

```
db.collection('user_batch').find({}, {name: 1, batchSize: 1}).toArray((err, result) => {
  if(err) 
    console.log(err)
  else
    console.log(result)
})
```

If I just pass **{name: 1}** then it will project _id and name. But if I pass **batchSize** then it will return entire document.

Note: I'm not facing this issue while executing this query in Mongo Shell

Comment: Which specific node driver version are you using? Just want to confirm which versions are affected.

Comment: driver version - 2.2.28, mongo - 3.2.14, node - 6.9.3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct that the driver incorrectly interprets this as the `batchSize` option and ignores the projection statement.

The correct way to do this though in modern driver releases is to actually use the [`.project()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#project) "cursor method" instead. This is more consistent with other language driver implementations.

```
    db.collection('collection').find()
      .project({ name: 1, batchSize: 1})
      .toArray();
```

As a full demonstration:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb'),
      MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;


(async function() {

  let db;

  try {
    db = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

    // New form uses .project() as a cursor method
    let result = await db.collection('collection').find()
      .project({ name: 1, batchSize: 1})
      .toArray();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result,undefined,2));

    // Legacy form confuses this as being a legacy "cursor option"
    let other = await db.collection('collection')
      .find({},{ name: 1, batchSize: 1 })
      .toArray();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(other,undefined,2));

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    db.close()
  }

})()
```

Produces the output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "594baf96256597ec035df23c",
    "name": "Batch 1",
    "batchSize": 30
  },
  {
    "_id": "594baf96256597ec035df234",
    "name": "Batch 2",
    "batchSize": 50
  }
]
[
  {
    "_id": "594baf96256597ec035df23c",
    "name": "Batch 1",
    "batchSize": 30,
    "users": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "594baf96256597ec035df234",
    "name": "Batch 2",
    "batchSize": 50,
    "users": []
  }
]
```

Where the first output form is the corrected one, using [`.project()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#project)

Comment: `project()` or `projection` is still valid for today with `node` to include or exclude fields.

Answer (score 6):

*The syntax of `Find` has changed.  Below is what I needed to know to solve this problem. This is excerpted from https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/CHANGES_3.0.0.md#find*

#### Find

`find` and `findOne` no longer support the `fields` parameter. You can achieve the same results as
the `fields` parameter by using `Cursor.prototype.project` or by passing the `projection` property
in on the options object . Additionally, `find` does not support individual options like `skip` and
`limit` as positional parameters. You must either pass in these parameters in the `options` object,
or add them via `Cursor` methods like `Cursor.prototype.skip`.

2.x syntax:

```
const cursor = coll.find({ a: 42 }, { someField: 1 });
```

3.x syntax:

```
const cursor = coll.find({ a: 42 }).project({ someField: 1 });

/* OR */

const cursor = coll.find({ a: 42 }, { projection: { someField: 1 } });
```