# How to search by a specific object value in array and return only the object searched in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js

I'm trying to query for an object value nested in array and return only this value (together with the entire object it nested in)

i have tried the following code but it return all the affiliates in the affiliate array while i only want the one i searched :

```
// data structure : 
{
  _id: 1,
  name: vendorName,
  countryCode: US,
  affiliates: [{
      number: 1,
      name: affName
    },
    {
      number: 2,
      name: affName
    }
  ]

async function getDetails(user){

    let vendorQuery = {
        countryCode: user.countryCode,
        affiliates: {
          $elemMatch: {
            number: user.affiliateNumber
          }
        }
    }
    let db = await mongoService.connect()
    const collection = db.collection('vendors');
    let vendorDetails = await collection.find( vendorQuery, {'affiliates.$':1} ).toArray()
    console.log('brokerDetails : ',brokerDetails);

    return vendorDetails
}
```

So in code above i expect the vendor object to be returned , but only with the matched affiliate and not all of them

Comment: You need to use the `.project()` method syntax as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098742/batchsize-field-name-ignored-in-field-projection). Like - `let vendorDetails = await collection.find( vendorQuery).project({'affiliates.$':1}).toArray()`

Comment: Thanks , it worked! i dont understand why the syntex in the Docs id different. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $ projection operator to return only the matched value from the array.

Also, `affiliatesQuery` need stop be a part of `countryQuery`, and that whole should be the first argument of your `find` query.

Second argument of the `find` query is supposed to be `projection`.

Try this :

```
let countryQuery = {
    countryCode: user.countryCode,
    affiliates.number: user.affiliateNumber
  }

  let db = await mongoService.connect()
  const collection = db.collection('vendors');
  let vendorDetails = await collection.find(countryQuery, {'affiliates.$':1}).toArray()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answar , but i still get the 2 object in the affiliates array

Comment: can you show your query, what you tried, cause $ only returns one element (first matched element from the array)

Comment: Yes, i've edited the code according to the new one , please take a look

Comment: apperently it should be collection.find( vendorQuery).project({'affiliates.$':1}).toArray() , thanks for the help

Comment: It is same, what I was suggesting was also a projection syntax, I don't know why it was not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use aggregation pipeline

```
const db = await mongoService.connect();
const collection = db.collection('vendors');
const result = await collection.aggregate([
  // query documents
  {
    $match: {
      countryCode: user.countryCode,
      'affiliates.number': user.affiliateNumber,
    }
  },
  // unwind affiliates array
  {
    $unwind : '$affiliates',
  },
  // filter docs again
  {
    $match: {
      'affiliates.number': user.affiliateNumber,
    },
  },
  // you can even replace root of the doc and return just object you need
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$affiliates" }
  }
])

return result
```