# Mongo projection query results vary from testing in shell vs nodejs application

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi I'm trying to filter fields from queried doc

here is the sample data

```
db.inventory.insertMany( [
   {_id: 1, item: "journal", qty: 25, size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" }, status: "A" },
   {_id: 2, item: "notebook", qty: 50, size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, status: "A" },
   {_id: 3, item: "paper", qty: 100, size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, status: "D" },
   {_id: 4, item: "planner", qty: 75, size: { h: 22.85, w: 30, uom: "cm" }, status: "D" },
   {_id: 5, item: "postcard", qty: 45, size: { h: 10, w: 15.25, uom: "cm" }, status: "A" }
]);
```

the query `db.inventory.find({_id:1},{size:0}).pretty()`

returns below doc suppressing the size feild

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "journal", "qty" : 25, "status" : "A" }
```

implementing the same in node js application

```
db.collection("inventory").findOne({ _id: 1 }, { "size": 0 }, (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve(result);
                    }
                })
```

returns the doc as is without suppressing the size field.

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "item": "journal",
    "qty": 25,
    "size": {
        "h": 14,
        "w": 21,
        "uom": "cm"
    },
    "status": "A"
}
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something here or doing it wrong. I don't want to use Mongoose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [batchSize field name ignored in Field Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098742/batchsize-field-name-ignored-in-field-projection) or (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807267/node-js-mongodb-findone-return-one-field-not-working) Marking it as dup..

Answer (score 2):

The [findOne](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOne) function in the node.js driver has a slightly different definition than the one in the shell.

Try

```
db.collection("inventory").findOne({ _id: 1 }, {projection:{ "size": 0 }}, (err, result) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

May you should try this
``` db.collection("inventory").findOne({ _id: 1 }). select("-size"). exec((err, ``result) => {//body of the fn}) ; ```