# MongoDB returns the id even if I tell it not to

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to retrive data from my collection. I saw that I need to put `{_id: 0}` in the options of my `db.collection.find()` method. So I have the following line :

```
 collectionPoints.find({ points: {$gt: -1} }, {_id: 0}).toArray();
```

However, this returns me the id of the documents like this :

```
  {
    _id: 5ee7a57be7179a6b636a7ac3,
    name: 'David',
    points: 0,
    perfect: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5ee7a589e7179a6b636a7ac4,
    name: 'Simon',
    points: 0,
    perfect: 0
  },
```

I do not understand what I am doing wronge here.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62301374/2282634

Comment: Wow, yes, I would never have found
Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo projection query results vary from testing in shell vs nodejs application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295133/mongo-projection-query-results-vary-from-testing-in-shell-vs-nodejs-application)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [batchSize field name ignored in Field Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098742/batchsize-field-name-ignored-in-field-projection) or (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807267/node-js-mongodb-findone-return-one-field-not-working) - Marking it as dup..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer found by Joe with this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62301374/10891826

I had to modify the `{ _id: 0 }` into `{ projection: { _id: 0 } }`.

```
collectionPoints.find({ points: { $gt: -1 } }, { projection: { _id: 0 } }).toArray();
```